# AngularJS add Action to Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been using other MVC Frameworks but I'm new to AngularJS and have ran into an issue. I have a controller called "Projects" and the route is /projects but I want to be able to do /projects/java where i would call a new page template/view and display that content.

How would I do this in AngularJS? Is there a way to create actions for projects or would I have to do something else?

```
angular
    .module('konradApp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                title        : 'Welcome',
                templateUrl  : 'views/main.html',
                controller   : 'MainCtrl',
                controllerAs : 'main'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                title        : 'About',
                templateUrl  : 'views/about.html',
                controller   : 'AboutCtrl',
                controllerAs : 'about'
            })
            .when('/projects', {
                title        : 'Projects',
                templateUrl  : 'views/projects.html',
                controller   : 'ProjectsCtrl',
                controllerAs : 'projects'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                title        : 'Contact',
                templateUrl  : 'views/contact.html',
                controller   : 'ContactCtrl',
                controllerAs : 'contact'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo : '/'
            });
    });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('konradApp')
    .controller('ProjectsCtrl', function () {

    });
```

Comment: where is your code :-)

Comment: Atleast give some code of how you are routing your app.

Comment: @JqueryKing I added my app's code & the projects controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do this using something called $routeParams which will allow you to code out your views. As a result your route configuration becomes:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            title        : 'Welcome',
            templateUrl  : 'views/main.html',
            controller   : 'MainCtrl',
        })
        .when('/:view', {
            title        :  function($routeParams){return $routeParams.view},
            templateUrl  : function(params){return 'views/'+params.view+'.html'},
            controller   : function($routeParams){return $routeParams.view+'Ctrl'},
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });
});
```

Comment: I see a bunch of 404's when you approach it like this, seems like a bad idea tbh.

Comment: I agree that this can cause 404's or bad routing based on a non-existant view. In order to ensure that they would have to handle this scenario by expanding their functions to deal with or redirect based on a bad url. But this can easily be expanded based upon the example given.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is a way to add nested views. Refer to the ui-router docs on how to do that: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

The idea is to add a nested ui-view in your projects.html and add a child route for your sub-view.